# How do I swap values in two columns by applying a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data set that has various columns. I want to swap values where the minimum temperature(tmin) is bigger than the maximum temperature(tmax) by applying a function.

The function I want to apply:

```
def swap(a,b):
    if a >= b:
        return b,a
    else:
        return a,b
```

Applying it:

```
cam.apply(lambda row: swap(row['tmin'], row['tmax']), axis=1)
```

when i check if the code worked, I find that it didn't change anything
`cam.query('tmin>tmax')`

```
station       date  year  month  day  rain  tmin  tmax

126  garoua  1954-05-07  1954      5  127  NaN   35.6  33.8

2012 garoua  1959-07-06  1959      7  187  NaN   33.0  31.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way indexing the dataframe on the rows where `tmin` is greater than `tmax` and using [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to swap the values in both columns:

```
# columns to be used for indexing
cols = ["tmin","tmax"]
#indices where tmin is greater than tmax
ixs = df.tmin.gt(df.tmax)
# Where ixs is True, values are swapped
df.loc[ixs,cols] = df.loc[ixs, cols].reindex(columns=cols[::-1]).values

      station    date     year  month  day  rain  tmin  tmax
126   garoua  1954-05-07  1954      5  127   NaN  33.8  35.6
2012  garoua  1959-07-06  1959      7  187   NaN  31.6  33.0
```

---

Or using [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
df[cols] = df[cols].where(df.tmin.lt(df.tmax), df[cols[::-1]].values)

      station    date     year  month  day  rain  tmin  tmax
126   garoua  1954-05-07  1954      5  127   NaN  33.8  35.6
2012  garoua  1959-07-06  1959      7  187   NaN  31.6  33.0
```

Comment: Thank you yatu, it worked. Can you please explain the code?

Comment: Sure @JusteNyirimana, added some explanations. Check the docs on `where` for more info. Let me know if you have more doubts :)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['diff'] = df['tmin'] - df['tmax]
df = df[df['diff']>= 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GRAPHLAB module for handling columns in Dataset

```
import graphlab as gl
data=gl.SFrame('demo.csv')
data
if data['age'].all() > 0:
    data['temp'] = data['age']
    data['age'] = data['weight']
    data['weight'] = data['temp']
    data['temp'] = 1
data
```

The above code which i used for handling Tables using GRAPHLAB MODULE [REFER THIS IMAGE , TO KNOW ABOUT ABOUT THE CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPg1u.png)

Answer (score -1):

First, I assume you are using the Python package Pandas?

If so, the apply function returns the result. You probably want to save this result in the original columns if you want to see any effect. Example:

```
cam[['tmin', 'tmax']] = cam.apply(lambda row: swap(row['tmin'], row['tmax']), axis=1)
```